# Add ID to image within Advanced Custom Fields image basic display

Tags: php, css, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to target images within a slideshow specifically using CSS.

I'm using Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields to generate image DIVs using PHP.

My code:

```
<?php $image = get_field('product1_image1');

    $size = 'large'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    if( $image ) {

    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
} ?>
```

This code generates something like this:

```
<img width="2000" height="1333" src="http://www.johanvanhengel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/TOR_for_Montis_by_Lambi__Van_Hengel_04-2000x1333.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large cycle-slide cycle-sentinel" alt="text" sizes="(max-width: 2000px) 100vw, 2000px" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: hidden;">
```

I would like to give the generated IMG-tag a ID of 'product1_image1' so that it can be targeted using css.

ex #product1_image1 { opacity:1; }

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Change..

`echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );`

into:

`echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, '', array( "id" => "product1_image1" ) );`

As you will see in the documentation the function supports attributes as a fourth parameter; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [danjah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3596285/danjah) is completeley correct but I would go a bit further just to increase the readability of the code...

Try this code:

```
<?php 
  $acf_img = get_field('product1_image1');

  $size = 'large'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
  if( $acf_img ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $acf_img, $size );

    echo '<img src="'.$image[0].'" width="'.$image[1].'" height="'.[2].'" class="your-class" id="product1_image1" />';
  } 
?>
```

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` creates an array of your image. `[0] => source, [1] => width, [2] => height`.

In the end it makes no difference but I think that this code is ore readable because you can directly see the html markup that is put out.
AND: you have full control over your markup - sometimes WordPress changes the output of some functions which is not wanted everytime. (they implemented `srcsets` e.g. and I didn't want it on my sites because I use a framework that changes my image sizes based on the viewport...)